# Valid URL for downloading Imagenet dataset?

Tags: download, dataset, imagenet

does anyone know where I can find a valid URL where I can download the ImageNet dataset?
The official webpage http://www.image-net.org/index states that the dataset is no longer publicly available.

Comment: I'm using this instead: https://www.dolthub.com/blog/2019-11-01-imagenet-in-dolt/

Hope this can help !

Answer (score 4):

Download tar files for train and val set for imagenet. If using wget in terminal:

1. `wget https://image-net.org/data/ILSVRC/2012/ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar --no-check-certificate`
2. `wget https://image-net.org/data/ILSVRC/2012/ILSVRC2012_img_val.tar --no-check-certificate`

After you have two tar files, in the same directory, download [official Pytorch example script](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/imagenet/extract_ILSVRC.sh) and run it.

- `. ./extract_ILSVRC.sh`

You will have a new folder called `imagenet/` with proper folders hierarchy. It will be recognized by Pytorch ImageFolder dataloader as something like:

```
from torchvision import datasets

train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('imagenet/train', transform=transform)
val_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('imagenet/val', transform=transform)
```

Answer (score 0):

check [www.kaggle.com](http://www.kaggle.com) and use their API to download ImageNet.
https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/imagenet-object-localization-challenge/data